# regex stops after first match - I need it to continue

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
source_IP = re.findall(r':name\s+[\(]Anti-Spoof-firewallX-eth2-02[\)]\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*\s+.*:Name\s+[\(](.*)+[\)]'
```

running against the following text:

```
:name (Anti-Spoof-firewallX-eth2-02)
        )
        :ip_convention_object ()
        :color (black)
        :comments ()
        :group_convention_query ()
        :group_sort_type (3)
        :is_convention_on (false)
        :member_class (network_object)
        :members_query ()
        :type (group)
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-10.10.24.0_s22)
            :Uid ("{DACDEBF9-C041-4C48-928E-92ECCC606CD5}")
        )
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-10.1.90.0_s23)
            :Uid ("{3E947D4C-677-45B4-AFCC-553351A7F03E}")
        )
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-100.141.28.0_s23)
            :Uid ("{3EE3901E-7490-4FDF-A66C-C452D17794}")
        )
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-10.20.20.0_s22)
            :Uid ("{51EED8DA-BFDB-42CD-8C3B-71DRRR6111E}")
        )
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-10.19.32.0_s23)
            :Uid ("{58CDB-6FDC-4F42-8F6B-3933428EB408}")
        )
        : (ReferenceObject
            :Table (network_objects)
            :Name (n-10.11.16.64_s27)
            :Uid ("{1D9A7204-ADE5-4414-B264-EA51A8TRE87}")
        )
    )
```

I need all of the IP address but the regex only returns the first one (n-10.10.24.0s22). How can I correct my regex?

Comment: Have u used the 'g' option?

Comment: Are you wanting all the IPs from the block? [`r':Name \([a-z0-9_\-.]*\)'`](https://regex101.com/r/XmBpG3/1/)

Comment: Correct, I need the return output to be a list of all the IPs listed --- i.e. ['n-10.10.24.0_s22', 'n-10.1.90.0_s23', 'n-100.141.28.0_s23', 'n-10.20.20.0_s22', 'n-10.19.32.0_s23', 'n-10.11.16.64_s27'].....but the regex has to begin at Anti-Spoof-firewallX-eth2-02. I have a document that contains several group names of firewall groups, I need to extract the IP address from each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a simpler regex, something like `:Name\s+\(([^\)]+)\)`.

Explanation:

`:Name` find  `Name:`

`\s+` followed by one or more spaces

`\(` followed by `(`

`([^\)]+)` capturing everything inside the `()`; if it's possible for the parenthesis to be empty change `+` to `*`

`\)` ending with `)`

The documentation for [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) says:

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

So the first bit of your regex is unneccessary and limiting.

```
import re

source_IP = re.findall(r':Name\s+\(([^\)]+)\)',':name (Anti-Spoof-firewallX-eth2-02) ) :ip_convention_object () :color (black) :comments () :group_convention_query () :group_sort_type (3) :is_convention_on (false) :member_class (network_object) :members_query () :type (group) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-10.10.24.0_s22) :Uid ("{DACDEBF9-C041-4C48-928E-92ECCC606CD5}") ) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-10.1.90.0_s23) :Uid ("{3E947D4C-677-45B4-AFCC-553351A7F03E}") ) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-100.141.28.0_s23) :Uid ("{3EE3901E-7490-4FDF-A66C-C452D17794}") ) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-10.20.20.0_s22) :Uid ("{51EED8DA-BFDB-42CD-8C3B-71DRRR6111E}") ) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-10.19.32.0_s23) :Uid ("{58CDB-6FDC-4F42-8F6B-3933428EB408}") ) : (ReferenceObject :Table (network_objects) :Name (n-10.11.16.64_s27) :Uid ("{1D9A7204-ADE5-4414-B264-EA51A8TRE87}") ) )')

print(source_IP)
# outputs: ['n-10.10.24.0_s22', 'n-10.1.90.0_s23', 'n-100.141.28.0_s23', 'n-10.20.20.0_s22', 'n-10.19.32.0_s23', 'n-10.11.16.64_s27']
```

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lU9iK4/7)